# Mysqli não encontrado em imagem docker

Tags: php, mysqli, docker

Eu subi uma aplicação PHP com mysql através do `docker-compose.yml`:

```bsh
version: '3'

volumes:
  data:

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=socialmedia

  phpadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1

  apache:
    image: 'php:7.2-apache'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
```

Porém, ao tentar conectar com o banco no código PHP:

```bsh
<?php
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Este **erro** acontece:

*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/database/connection.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/database/connection.php on line 7*

Aparentemente a imagem do docker, `php:7.2-apache`, não possui o mysqli.

Como faço para solucionar o problema e me **conectar** com o banco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um Dockerfile, e instale o mysqli nele

https://hub.docker.com/_/php referência.

Vá até a sessão How to install more PHP extensions

E no seu docker-compose.yml ao invés de instalar de uma imagem, instale desse Dockerfile. Veja esse exemplo: https://github.com/samhk222/generic.docker.apache/blob/master/docker-compose.yml